# EF6: Full-text Search with Database First Approach

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I found this [link](http://www.entityframework.info/Home/FullTextSearch) to make `full-text search` work through `linq`. However, the code seems to be targeting `database first approach`. How to make it work with `Database First Approach`?

Relevant part of code:

```
public class NoteMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Note>
{
    public NoteMap()
    {
        // Primary Key
        HasKey(t => t.Id);
    }
}
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    static MyContext()
    {
        DbInterception.Add(new FtsInterceptor());
    }
    public MyContext(string nameOrConnectionString) : base(nameOrConnectionString)
    {
    }
    public DbSet<Note> Notes { get; set; }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new NoteMap());
    }
}
```

As seen above the function `OnModelCreating` is only called in `Code First Approach`. I wonder what needs to change to make the code in link work for `Database First` approach

Comment: It will work fine in "Database first" if you use the "EF Reverse POCO" template for code generation iso EDMX

Comment: @ErikEJ Can you explain in a little more detail and if there is a way to make it work without much modifications in code.

Comment: Did you actually try to run that code for your case? For code described at your link it does not matter database first or model first approach is used. Yes, OnModelCreating is not called in database first, but it is also not related to implementing full-text search in any way. All that matters is FtsInterceptor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I tried implementing the solution without `OnModelCreating` altogether and it turns out that it is not even needed for `FullText` interceptor implementation as @Evk suggested.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest different approach. Create Table-valued function with fulltext search on SQL server and call it from Entity Framework with parameter. Simplified example from my project which search fulltext over two tables and can be easily called from EF:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetRealtyMapFulltext]
(@criteria nvarchar(4000))
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN (SELECT 
   realty.Id AS realtyId,
   ( COALESCE(ftR.Rank,0) + COALESCE(ftObec.Rank,0)) AS FtRank
   FROM realty
   LEFT JOIN ruian_obec ON realty.obecId = ruian_obec.obec_kod
   Left JOIN CONTAINSTABLE(Realty, *, @criteria) ftR ON realty.Id = ftR.[Key] 
   Left JOIN CONTAINSTABLE(ruian_obec, *, @criteria) ftObec ON realty.obecId = ftObec.[Key] 
   AND ( COALESCE(ftR.Rank,0) + COALESCE(ftObec.Rank,0)  > 0)
```

Comment: Facing this [issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40686625/sql-nested-query-does-not-have-appropriate-key) if I try to utilize table valued functions

Answer (score 1):

Database-first generates all classes as partials including very handy partial `OnContextCreated` method.

I can not test it at the moment, but you could try adding MyContext_FTS.cs file with following code :

```
public partial class MyContext
{
    partial void OnContextCreated()
    {         
          DbInterception.Add(new FtsInterceptor());
    }
}
```